# solid brush property not binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, brush

I have a class X there are some data:

```
private string yyy;

public string YYY
{
    get { return yyy; }
    set
    {
        yyy= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("YYY");
    }
}

private SolidBrush color;

public SolidBrush Color
{
    get { return color; }
    set
    {
        color= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
    }
}
```

My Data Grid bind to this class like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="yyy" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YYY}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

When I do  Foreground="Red" it works but with the binding it does not work, why?

The value that I put to brush it like this:

```
this.Color = new SolidBrush(color);
```

color is a variable that contains any color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing [System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx) with  [System.Drawing.SolidBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.aspx), which is not part of WPF.

You have to use `SolidColorBrush` instead of `SolidBrush`.